# Dragging an element inside a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have created a circle using Javascript and want to drag an element inside it .Since the circle is created inside the div and 
the  div  is always a rectangle ,the element is dragged inside the rectangular div instead of the circle.Would it be 
possible to drag an element inside a circle.

Comment: Show code or it didn't happen...

Comment: Without code don't quite understande what you wanting, please clarify. You can use border-radius to make any div look circular in a modern browser.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871498/draggable-object-glued-to-border